# Include Headings in Quill Rich Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quill

I am working on quill rich editor, i need all headings (h1....h6). I have tried different ways but it just shows (h1 and h2) and sometimes it show 3 headings.

**Html code:**

```
<div id="standalone-container">
    <div id="toolbar-container">
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <select class="ql-font"></select>
          <select class="ql-header"></select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-bold"></button>
          <button class="ql-italic"></button>
          <button class="ql-underline"></button>
          <button class="ql-strike"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <select class="ql-color"></select>
          <select class="ql-background"></select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
          <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
          <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="editor-container" style="height: 400px;"> </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="blog_description" id="blog_description" required="">
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
<script src="{{url('quill/quill.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>           
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
        modules: {
          // formula: true,
          // syntax: true,
          toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
        },
        placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        theme: 'snow'
      });
 </script>
```

How can i display all headings in quill editor? I would appreciate if anypne guide me through this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following ([copy paste gives new line](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/861#issuecomment-239961806)):

```js
//#region Fix for copy paste giving new line
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
Block.tagName = 'div';
Quill.register(Block);
//#endregion

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    // formula: true,
    // syntax: true,
    toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.snow.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<div id="standalone-container">
  <div id="toolbar-container">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-font"></select>
      <select class="ql-header">
        <option value="1">Heading 1</option>
        <option value="2">Heading 2</option>
        <option value="3">Heading 3</option>
        <option value="4">Heading 4</option>
        <option value="5">Heading 5</option>
        <option value="6">Heading 6</option>
        <option value="">Normal</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-strike"></button>
      </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-color"></select>
      <select class="ql-background"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
      <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
      <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="editor-container" style="height: 400px;"> </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="blog_description" id="blog_description" required="">
</div>
```

Comment: How can i remove the default spaces included by quill( i.e.  <p><br></p>) ?

Comment: @AmirKhan I don't understand what you're asking? You mean when we press enter?

Comment: I just copy paste a content with multiple paragraphs, the quill include a default  <p><br></p> which makes it a little awkward. I don't want the extra spaces added by quill..

Comment: I tried copy paste, it doesn't add <p><br></p> tags explicitly, though I understand they are in the DOM

Comment: Let me clear it, i past some paragraphs in quill. Add one space (one enter) between each paragraph. i stored the content in database and when i fetched it in blogs section the quill added one additional space (i.e. one enter) between each paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, I've reproduced it, let me see if it can be solved

Comment: It is behaving like this:
<p>Paragraph</p><p><br></p>
<p>Paragraph</p><p><br></p>
<p>Paragraph</p><p><br></p>
<p>Paragraph</p><p><br></p>

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, but now i face another problem i print the data as {!! 
 substr($blog['description'],0,200) !!} as i need only 200 character in the catagory page. After applying the above solution the substr function is not working. How can I display specific amount of character from this now?

Comment: No way this has just this small amount of up-votes. This answer is perfect. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @EnzoDtz glad that it helped!

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the documentation, the Normal should be `selected`, in order to be highlighted.
Also the value should not be there or the editor will wrap the Blot with an `undefined` tag.

> The `ql-toolbar` class will be added to the toolbar container and Quill attach appropriate handlers to `<button>` and `<select>` elements with a class name in the form `ql-${format}`. Buttons element may optionally have a custom `value` attribute.

```html
  <select class="ql-size">
    <option value="small"></option>
    <!-- Note a missing, thus falsy value, is used to reset to default -->
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="large"></option>
    <option value="huge"></option>
  </select>
```

So applied in the heading case:

```
      <select class="ql-header">
        <option value="1">Heading 1</option>
        <option value="2">Heading 2</option>
        <option value="3">Heading 3</option>
        <option value="4">Heading 4</option>
        <option value="5">Heading 5</option>
        <option value="6">Heading 6</option>
        <option selected>Normal</option>
      </select>
```